# AttachmentBuilder Discord.js V14

Tags: discord, discord.js, chatbot, attachment

This error is keep coming and i don't know how to fix it. I have try look at similiar post but none of the solution work [The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB2uP.png) my code is look like this

```
if(commandName === "download"){
        const {options} = interaction;
        if(options.getSubcommand() === "twitter"){
            const url = options.getString("link")
            try {
        const tweetID = getStatusID(url);
        const tweet = await getTweet(tweetID);
        const media = parseMedia(tweet);
        if (media.type === "video" || media.type === "animated_gif") {
            try {

                const videos = []
                media.media.forEach((p) => {
                    videos.push(new AttachmentBuilder().setFile(p.url).setDescription(`Video from ${media.user}`));
                })
                console.log(media.media)
                console.log(videos)
                await interaction.reply({content: `Videos from ${media.user}`, files: [...videos]});
            } catch (error1) {
                console.log(error1.message)
                interaction.reply("error while downloading tweet")
            }
        }

        if (media.type === "photo") {
            const photos = [];
            media.media.forEach((p) => {
                photos.push(new AttachmentBuilder().setFile(p.url).setDescription(`Photos from ${media.user}`));
            });
            console.log(photos)
            await interaction.reply({content: `Photos from ${media.user}`, files: [...photos]});
        }
        // await waitMsg.delete();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Failed to download tweet", error.message);
    }
        }
    }
```

here my parseMedia function

```
function parseMedia(status) {
    const caption = status.text || status.full_text;
    const extendedEntities = status.extended_entities;
    let media = [];
    let type = '';
    if(extendedEntities && extendedEntities.media) {
    media = extendedEntities.media.map((obj) => {
        const tmp = {};
        type = obj.type;
        if(obj.type === 'video' || obj.type === 'animated_gif') {
            const videos = obj.video_info.variants;
            // console.log('videos', videos);
            let selectedVideo = videos;
            if (obj.type === 'video') {
            selectedVideo = videos.filter((f) => f.bitrate);
        }
        selectedVideo = selectedVideo.reduce((prev, current) => (prev.bitrate > current.bitrate) ? prev : current);
        tmp.type = obj.type;
        tmp.thumbnail = obj.media_url_https;
        tmp.url = selectedVideo.url;
        } 
        
        if (obj.type === 'photo') {
        tmp.type = obj.type;
        tmp.thumbnail = obj.media_url_https;
        tmp.url = obj.media_url_https;
        }
        return tmp;
        });

        return {
        user: status.user.screen_name,
        caption,
        url: `https://twitter.com/${status.user.screen_name}/status/${status.id_str}`,
        type,
        media
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have tried to change into embed

```
if (media.type === "photo") {
            const photos = [];
            media.media.forEach((p) => {
                photos.push(new AttachmentBuilder().setFile(p.url).setDescription(`Photos from ${media.user}`));
            });
            console.log(photos)
            await interaction.reply({embeds: [...photos]});
        }
```

but the bot just return the description [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/641vm.png)

here my console.log [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7FGc.png)